# Can I get the phone number of an SMS message to a skype number using the skype4py?

Tags: skype4py

using the skype4py wrapper, can I get the phone number from an sms message to my skype number?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show some more of your work?  What have you tried?  What errors have you seen? Show some code samples. Otherwise this question may be closed because it is low quality.

Answer (score 0):

SMS object API as it is in Skype4Py

https://github.com/stigkj/Skype4Py/blob/master/Skype4Py/sms.py

Looks it has `ReplyToNumber`.

I suggest you push your luck with it.